# Table rows not visible on Shiny App (DT Package)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am having troubles to display the rows of a simple table in my shiny app with the DT package (renderTable works fine):

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxQu9.png)

The code I am using in ui.r and server.r are:

- Server:

```
    output$table1 = renderDT({
         iris
       }, filter="top")
```

- UI:

```
    Tab_1_2 <- tabPanel("Instructions", 
                          
      HTML("<p>2) Text sample;.  </p>"),
      actionButton("B1", "Refresh"),
      tabPanel("", title = icon("user"), wellPanel(
      tags$h2("", class = "text-center", style = "padding-top: 0;"),
      DTOutput("table1")
      ))
    )
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The code you have provided here displays all rows. The image indicates the data passed to renderDT is empty. Something else in your code may be interfering?

Comment: I don't think so because it works fine with renderTable. The web console give the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: $table.DataTable is not a function

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the error is not reproducible with the code you have provided. Provide an MRE that reproduces the error and you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't upload the full code as it is too long. Nevertheless, I have noticed that the problem is in the UI.R file of the app. Could it be a problem to have a datatable inside 2 tabpanels and 1 wellpanel?? I am running out of ideas..

Comment: Hmm. I don't think rendering the DT inside nested tabpanels and a wellpanel should be a problem. To test if they are causing the problem, load the app without any structuring UI, in other words  leave the `DTOutput("table1")` as bare as possible and see if it renders correctly. I understand you not wanting to post your entire app because it's really long. Try to post a **minimal** example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! It helped me to find the problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! The process of creating a reproducible example has also helped me debug my apps. Good going!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but this part of the code was creating the problem:

tags$script(src ="require.js")